# Polynomials $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (-1)^i\frac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\binom{n}{2i}x^{n-2i}$ have $n$ real roots

Tags: calculus, polynomials, reference-request, roots

For any positive integer $n$, I conjecture that the polynomial

> $$P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\dbinom{n}{2i}x^{n-2i}$$

has $n$ real roots.

I've checked some polynomials in Mathematica and I strongly believe this result is true.

Does anyone have any reference or proof for this result?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a mathematical explanation for "seems to have". Could you make that more precise, please?

Comment: It would be useful to describe the problem where this polynomial has appeared. It can give insight on its properties.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I've edited the problem. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Same question as @user: why those polynomials? In principle, it's possible to get those rather special coefficients by some "mathematical doodling", and check the number of real zeros out of a whim, but it's not very likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at a small example. The first few such polynomials are:

- $P_0=1$
- $P_1=x$
- $P_2=x^2-1$
- $P_3=x^3-3x$
- $P_4=x^4-6x^2+3$

We can compute the total number of real roots of $P_4$ via [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem). The details are given at the linked Wikipedia article. The summary of how it works is that we apply the Euclidean algorithm to $P_4$ and $P_4'$, and remember the remainders we get at each step, with a suitable choice of sign. This is called the "canonical Sturm chain" for $P_4$. Then the the number of roots of $P_4$ in $(a,b)$ can be obtained by taking the difference between the number of sign changes we see in the canonical Sturm chain at $a$, and the number we see at $b$.

Explicitly, the polynomials we end up considering are:

- $P_4=x^4-6x^2+3$
- $P_4'=4x^3-12x=4P_3$
- $(\frac{1}{4}x)(4P_3)-P_4=x^4-3x^2-x^4+6x^2-3=3x^2-3=3P_2$
- $(\frac{4}{3}x)(3P_2)-4P_3=4x^3-4x-4x^3+12x=8x=8P_1$
- $(\frac{3}{8}x)(8P_1)-3P_2=3x^2-3x^2+3=3=3P_0$

Since the leading coefficient of each of these polynomials is positive and each has degree $1$ smaller than the one before, they alternate in sign near $-\infty$, so the sign sequence is $+-+-+$: there are $4$ changes of sign. Similarly, there are $0$ changes of sign near $\infty$ as all the polynomials are positive there. So Sturm's theorem tells us that $P_4$ has $4$ real roots.

---

The same argument works in general. We will establish the following two identities:

\begin{align}
P_n'&=nP_{n-1}\\
x P_{n-1}-P_n&=(n-1)P_{n-2}
\end{align}
Together, these imply that the canonical Sturm chain for $P_n$ consists of the polynomials $P_k$ for $k \leq n$, each scaled by some positive constant multiple. Since each $P_n$ is monic, this in turn means that the canonical Sturm chain has $n$ sign changes at $-\infty$ and $0$ sign changes at $\infty$, and so $P_n$ has $n$ real roots.

Each of these identities can be established by direct calculation. We adopt the convention that any coefficients which have negative factorials in the denominator are $0$; this allows us to forget about the upper limit of the sum. So:
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{(2i)!}{i!2^i}\binom{n}{i}x^{2n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{n!}{(n-2i)!i!2^k}x^{2n-i}$$

With this in mind, we have:
\begin{align}
P_n'(x)&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{n!}{(n-2i)!i!2^i}(n-2i)x^{n-1-2i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{n!}{(n-1-2i)!i!2^i}x^{n-1-2i}\\
&=n\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-2i)!i!2^i}x^{n-1-2i}\\
&=nP_{n-1}(x)
\end{align}
and:
\begin{align}P_n(x)-xP_{n-1}(x)&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \left[ \frac{n!}{(n-2i)!i!2^i}-\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-2i)!i!2^i}\right]x^{n-2i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-2i)!i!2^i}\left(\frac{n}{n-2i}-1\right)x^{n-2i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-2i)!i!2^i}\frac{2i}{n-2i}x^{n-2i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^i \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-2i)!(i-1)!2^{i-1}}x^{n-2i}\\
&=(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2i)!(i-1)!2^{i-1}}x^{n-2i}\\
&=-(n-1)\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2-2j)!j!2^j}x^{n-2-2j}\\
&=-(n-1)P_{n-2}(x)
\end{align}
which completes the proof.

---

(I don't know a whole lot about this, but Wikipedia tells me that polynomials which obey the identity $P_n'=nP_{n-1}$ form an [Appell sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_sequence), which means there may be a simpler or more intuitive way of thinking about all of this in terms of umbral calculus...)

Answer (score 4):

It will be demonstrated that
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\dbinom{n}{2i}x^{n-2i}\tag{1}$$ 
is the characteristic polynomial of the $n\times n$ dimensional matrix 
$$
M^{(n)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&\sqrt1&0&\dots& 0&0\\
\sqrt1& 0&\sqrt2&\dots& 0&0\\
0&\sqrt2&0&\ddots& 0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\ddots&0&\sqrt{n-1}\\
0&0&0&\dots&\sqrt{n-1}&0
\end{pmatrix},\tag{2}
$$
which can be recognized as a finite-dimensional version of the position operator for harmonic oscillator. In short writing $M_{ij}=\sqrt{i}\delta_{i,j-1}+\sqrt{j}\delta_{i-1,j}$.

Indeed the characteristic polynomials of the matrices $M^{(1)}$ and $M^{(2)}$ are $P_1(x)=x$ and $P_2(x)=x^2-1$, respectively. We are going to demonstrate that if expression (1) is valid for $n-1$ and $n-2$ it is valid for $n$ as well.
Let $A^{(n)}=xI^{(n)}-M^{(n)}$.

$$\begin{align}
P_n(x)&=|A^{(n)}|=x\left|A^{(n)}_{[nn]}\right|-\sqrt{n-1}\left|A^{(n)}_{[n,n-1]}\right|=x\left|A^{(n)}_{[nn]}\right|
-(n-1)\left|\left(A^{(n)}_{[n,n-1]}\right)_{[n-1,n-1]}\right|\\
&=x\left|A^{(n-1)}\right|
-(n-1)\left|A^{(n-2)}\right|=xP_{n-1}(x)-(n-1)P_{n-2}(x)\\
&\stackrel{I.H.}{=}x\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\dbinom{n-1}{2i}x^{n-2i-1}-(n-1)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\dbinom{n-2}{2i}x^{n-2i-2}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\dbinom{n-1}{2i}x^{n-2i}+(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i-2)!}{2^{i-1}\cdot (i-1)!}\dbinom{n-2}{2i-2}x^{n-2i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\dbinom{n-1}{2i}x^{n-2i}+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\dbinom{n-1}{2i-1}x^{n-2i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i\dfrac{(2i)!}{2^i\cdot i!}\dbinom{n}{2i}x^{n-2i}.\\
\end{align}
$$

Thus by induction the claim is proved. As matrices $M^{(n)}$ are hermitian (symmetric) all its eigenvalues and therefore the roots of the characteristic polynomials are real.

In the computation of the determinant the Laplace expansion was used with $A_{[i,j]}$ denoting $ij$-minor of $A$.

Comment: Thanks! I saw these polynomials long time ago and I remember they are related to some physics context, but I didn't remember they are related to harmonic oscillator.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, what you have are the so-called ["probabilists' Hermite polynomials"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition) (see [the DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.3.T1) as well).

That is,

$$P(x)=\operatorname{He}_n(x)=(-1)^n\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)=$$

and these *orthogonal polynomials* have long been established to have real roots, proven through either Sturmian sequences (as in Micah's answer) or through its having a symmetric Jacobi matrix (as in user's answer). See [Chihara's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=GiP0AwAAQBAJ) for more details.

Since you mention that you are using *Mathematica*, here is how to use it to verify the identity for the first few members:

```
And @@ Table[Expand[2^(-n/2) HermiteH[n, x/Sqrt[2]] == 
                    Sum[(-1)^i Binomial[n, 2 i] (2 i - 1)!! x^(n - 2 i),
                        {i, 0, Quotient[n, 2]}]],
             {n, 0, 20}]
   True
```